Could a crossterm in the energy–momentum relation be missing?
Could it be that $E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc )^2$ is really $E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + 2mpc^3 + (pc )^2$ or $E^2 = (mc^2)^2 - 2mpc^3 + (pc )^2$ so that it comes from $E^2 = (mc^2 + pc)^2$ or $E^2 = (mc^2 - pc)^2$? Dimensional analysis matches the $2mpc^3$ to the units of energy, and for $p=0$ it simplifies into $E=mc^2$.
Does the crossterm really make a difference in terms of orders of magnitude for the experiments in which the energy–momentum relation has been confirmed?

This is just a terrible question as it shows no effort to check such a basic fact.

That means it is a simple question to answer, but a perfectly reasonable doubt.

The Pythagorean theorem, which this relationship is consistent with, has no cross terms.

This is an extremely poor question. With your proposal, there will be no need for the square at all - it will just be $E =mc^2 + pc$.

No, it can't be.
The energy-momentum relation
$$E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$$
has been confirmed in countless experiments.
An energy-momentum relation with a cross-term $\pm 2mpc^3$ would contradict these experimental results, and thus has to be rejected.

Does the crossterm really make a difference in terms of orders of magnitude for those experiments?

For particles with not very small mass $m$ it would surely make a difference.
